# How to use two let's on the same line?

Tags: haskell, hugs

I'm using Hugs interpreter and I want to execute the following code (by Haskell 2010 language report):

```
let x = 1
z = x+y
in z+1
```

Is it possible only creating a `.hs` file and loading? Can I do it by command line directly?

Comment: Indent the `z =...` line so that the z lines up under the x. Use spaces, tabs can cause problems in Haskell.

Comment: doesn't ` let x = 1 in let z = x+y in z + 1` or `let x=1; z=x+y in z + 1` work? (I can only test in ghci and basically have no clue about hugs - sorry)

Comment: Hugs hasn't been maintained in years. Only a handful of people still use it. Why do you?

Comment: @Carsten booth works. Thanks!

Comment: @eightShirt I added it as an answer -  I hope you don't mind

Comment: @dfeuer it's probably the FP101x*Gate* thing ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you cannot enter multi-line statements into hugs in this case it is possible to do it all in one line.

You can use two `let ... in ...` like this:

```
let x = 1 in let z = x+y in z + 1
```

or you can use `;` for multiple definitions like this:

```
let x=1; z=x+y in z + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

(Sorry - didn't realize your question was about hugs not ghci.)

You can use `:{` in ghci to enter a multiline expression:

```
shell$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :{
Prelude|   let z = 1
Prelude|       w = 3
Prelude|   in z + w
Prelude| :}
4
Prelude>
```

Comment: Why is it sad for hugs to declare `let`s? (`:{`)